# Knockoutjs validation and server validation

Tags: html, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Hi I'm kind of new to Knockoutjs, I am in the scenario where I want to post a form where I have for example an email address, there is an requirement that the email address needs to be unique.

On the server I check if the email address is unique or not and then returns an validationjson class for example

{
 isEmailUnique: false,
 isPasswordStrongEnough: true;
}

How can I with knockoutjs validation show these errors in a neat way?

Answer (score 4):

I would use two different server side validators for this, since they affect different observables in the view model.

Originally taken from the [knockout validation readme](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation)

```
ko.validation.rules['isEmailUnique'] = {
   validator: function(val, param){
      var isValid = true;

      $.ajax({
          async: false,
          url: '/validation/isEmailUnique',
          type: 'POST',
          data: { value: val, param: param },
          success: function(response){
                 isValid = response === true;              
          },
          error: function(){
                 isValid = false; //however you would like to handle this              
          }
       });

       return isValid;
  },
  message: 'The Email is not unique'
};
```

Then on the server you need to create an endpoint that accepts POST requests where you perform your lookup and then return true or false depending on the result of the query.

To use the above validator

```
this.email = ko.observable()
   .extend({ 
      isEmailUnique: { 
         message: 'Something else perhaps? It will override the message in the validator' 
      } 
   });
```

You can use the very same thing for the password strength validation.

Using validators like this will fire validation when the observable changes, which can be a useful way to do validation.

Comment: I saw that post in their readme, but I would really like to do all the server side validation on submit with one call. If the registration is fine, return succeed else return the things that were wrong.

Comment: In that case you should probably not make use of the validation plugin at all for that particular case. Just POST the data you want to save and take care of the result. If you want to position the error messages next to the field that caused the error, you must figure out a convention for that. Maybe some computed observables that can filter the validation json or something which you can bind to. However, Knockout validation cannot help you there.

Comment: :( okeay, I wanted to use the other stuff as required and so on. So there is no way to "trigger" an validation error when I receive the result from the server?

Comment: You can create a validation that depends on an observable that you can control. You could use that to "trigger" the validation. Just using the displaying things from KO validation so to speak.

Comment: My understanding is that making ajax calls with async false is generally a bad idea. I understand why you might want to do this so that you can use a single validator but I would think that there is a better way. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late, but for my 2 cents worth, I would take a more generic approach such as returning a standard JSON serialized AjaxResult class from your server endpoints (such as /Register) with properties such as Data (an arbitrary container used for, for example, an updated model to re-bind with the mapping plugin), and a collection of validation message strings, etc. Then you could have an HTML validation summary which is bound to an ObservableArray and push / map the messages from your Ajax result into there. This is essentially what I've been doing with Knockout and it works nicely.